# RegularExpression

Tags: regex

valid[NNP(POS)]

```html
valid[NNP(POS)]<br/>
valid[NN(POS)]<br/>
valid[NN(POS)]<br/>
valid[JJ(POS)]<br/>
```

Want to remove the [....]

$string = "ABC(Test1)";

echo preg_replace("/([^]]+]/","",$string);

This one working fine.

$string = "valid[NNP(POS)]";
This is not worlking andy help

Comment: I got it thi will work fine

Comment: echo preg_replace("/\[[^\]]*\]/","",$string);